# Verify a solution - Chain Rule

Tags: derivatives

I've submitted a homework assignment online where it is then marked by a program and a score is instantly given back.

I was 100% correct in all solutions besides this one.

Use the Chain Rule to find $\displaystyle \frac{dw}{dt}$.
$$
w = xe^{\frac{y}{z}},\,\,\,    x = t^5, \,\,\, y = 4 − t, \,\,\,   z = 2 + 4t
$$
$$
\frac{dw}{dt} = e^{\frac{y}{z}}(5t^4) - \frac{xe^{\frac{y}{z}}}{z}
$$

Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong? Apologies for the lack of formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the chain rule that says:
$$
\frac{dw}{dt} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}.
$$
Here it looks like you forgot $$\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}. $$